# Help understanding why built in voltage in PN junction created?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

I was reviewing basic semiconductor physics and need some help understanding where my logic is incorrect. For a basic PN junction, the process of forming the depletion region is described as follows:

1. When PN junction is created, diffusion due to the large concentration of electrons in N and holes in P causes recombination near the interface.
2. Left behind from the recombination is the now positive donor ions (who have lost an electron in recombination) and negative acceptor ions (who have gained an electron through recombination).
3. The density of stationary positive donor ions and stationary negative acceptor ions creates an electric field to oppose the diffusion current, eventually equilibrizing.

What I do not understand is step 3. We say that the donor/acceptor ions are "positive" and "negative" but I feel like these terms are in context of their original values. For example, if we have N dopants in group 5 and P dopants in group 3 and recombination occurs, shouldn't the new donor/acceptor ions both be "in group 4" (aka, they now have the same amount of electrons in bonding?). In my head it seems like donor ions losing an electron and acceptor ions gaining an electron would then make them have the same "charge density" as each other as now there are 4 valence electrons in each that are happy and bonded. In this case, I don't see why an electric field would be created to oppose the diffusion current?

I'm sure I am missing something basic and assuming something incorrect about how I am thinking about this, but I would appreciate any help. Let me know if I can clarify my question further.

Comment: Actually, I think I just answered this myself, maybe someone can let me know if it is correct. The donor/acceptor atoms are neutral, so when they lose/gain an electron they are now actually net positive or negative. I was treating the atom as a bundle of negative charge, when really it starts neutral so this would make sense then.

Comment: You figured it out.